# Conditional rendering without JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to do [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#element-variables) like below with `React.createElement`?

```
render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        {button}
      </div>
    );
}
```

I tried to do that like this :

```
render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = React.createElement("LogoutButton" { "onClick": this.handleLogoutClick }, null);
    } else {
      button = React.createElement("LogoutButton" { "onClick": this.handleLoginClick }, null);
    }

    return (
      React.createElement("div", null, {button});
    );
}
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: see: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Comment: `React.createElement("LogoutButton"` should be `React.createElement(LogoutButton`, where `LogoutButton` is a reference to that class/function.

Comment: you have an invalid syntax in `React.createElement("LogoutButton" { "onClick": this.handleLogoutClick }, null);`. Missing `,` . Also use `LogoutButton` instead of `"LogoutButton"`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = React.createElement("LogoutButton" { "onClick": this.handleLogoutClick }, null);
    } else {
      button = React.createElement("LogoutButton" { "onClick": this.handleLoginClick }, null);
    }

    return (
      React.createElement("div", null, {button});
    );
}
```

to

```
render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = React.createElement(LogoutButton, { "onClick": this.handleLogoutClick }, null);
    } else {
      button = React.createElement(LogoutButton, { "onClick": this.handleLoginClick }, null);
    }

    return (
      React.createElement("div", null, {button});
    );
}
```

Now your code should work properly and see [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) for any future reference